# Is the Java SOAP API deprecated?

Tags: api, soap, java

It seems that all of the documentation on the Salesforce website for a SOAP call is from 4+ years ago, and all of the example code contains old, and deprecated methods from the wsc library. Is there a different, more documented way to call the database with SOAP and Java?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector was last updated 1-2016 and the SOAP API is defiantly not depreciated

Comment: @Eric if the API is not depreciated, why does it use the ConnectorConfig class in the example, which is not generated by the WSDL?